# Java operator ? :

Tags: java

How can I change

```
if(xmlComboBoxValues.get(0) == null){
    cstmt.setNull(i++,java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR); 
}
else {  
    cstmt.setString(i++, (String) xmlComboBoxValues.get(0));            
}
```

as a ? : expressing in java?

Here is what I have but the syntax is obviously wrong.

```
xmlComboBoxValues.get(0) == (null) ? cstmt.setNull(i++,java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR) : cstmt.setNull(i++,java.sql.Types.NVARCHAR);
```

Comment: Why do you need this? Feels like it would hugely sacrifice readability.

Comment: remove the brackets around `null`  `xmlComboBoxValues.get(0) == null`and it should be ok.

Comment: Expressions in the ternary operator must result in the same type and it cannot be a `void` method call, so you can't do that.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking for the impossible.

Comment: @EJP Asking for the impossible in itself shoudln't be off-topic. The _"It is not possible because..."_ is a valid answer.

Comment: @icza You can indeed answer that it's impossible, but it's still off-topic.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that for two reasons:

- The methods have a `void` return type
- You can't use a conditional expression as a statement

These are both symptoms of the same cause: you're misusing the operator. The purpose of the operator is to choose which of two expressions to use as the result of the overall expression... which is then used for something else. Computing an expression has slightly different aim from executing a statement.

Your original code is already idiomatic: if a condition is true, you want to execute one statement. Otherwise, you want to execute a different statement. Perfect for `if`/`else`.

Comment: Thank Jon, I have 10 comboboxes which act as filters for a table. Having an `if/else` for each combobox makes my code looks bulky so I thought of trying to put all on one line using the ? : operator.

Comment: @RicoStrydom: Sounds like you should put your combo boxes in a collection, the you only need to have that code once, in a loop. Alternatively, if you can't do that, extract the common code into a method you call for each of your combo boxes.

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that with `Ternary` operator in `Java` since `setNull()` is `void` method.

From [§JLS.15.25](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25):

```
ConditionalExpression:
ConditionalOrExpression
ConditionalOrExpression ? Expression : ConditionalExpression
```

> The conditional operator is syntactically right-associative (it groups
>   right-to-left). Thus, a?b:c?d:e?f:g means the same as
>   a?b:(c?d:(e?f:g)).
>
> The conditional operator has three operand expressions. ? appears
>   between the first and second expressions, and : appears between the
>   second and third expressions.
>
> The first expression must be of type boolean or Boolean, or a
>   compile-time error occurs.
>
> **It is a compile-time error for either the second or the third operand
>   expression to be an invocation of a void method.**